# get latest month and year from separate columns R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe (in R) with separate columns for month and year. for each group in the dataframe, I want to get the last 12 months in the series. It the data is missing one of the most recent months, I want to replace with a month from the previous year. For example, suppose I want to get data for 2020 (January - December), but the most recent data for a group is September, then I would want to pull October-December from 2019. I just can't quite figure out how to do this.

Here is an example.

```
a = expand.grid(1:2,2019,1:12)
b = expand.grid(1:2,2020,1:9)
dat = rbind(a,b)
names(dat) = c("group","year","month")
dat = dat[order(dat$group,dat$year,dat$month),]
```

So the data looks like this:

```
   group year month
1      1 2019     1
3      1 2019     2
5      1 2019     3
7      1 2019     4
9      1 2019     5
11     1 2019     6
```

Comment: Does your data have more than two years?  If so, how do you handle the case when, say, 2019 and 2020 both have missing data?  Do you fill in 2019 first from 2018, and then fill in 2020 with the updated 2019 data?  Or do you only look one year back in the original data (in which case 2020 would show NA for the missing months in 2019 and 2020)?

Comment: I only need to look back one year, as the data is complete for each month. I just have cases where the data has not come in and so I need to adjust for the different groups.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure, would it be enough to always get the last 12 entries of your data by group? In this case the approach below would work.

This approach assumes that:

1. Each month is one row / observation (there are no double entries for one month).
2. If a month is `NA` it will be "drawn" as well.
3. You are always interested in getting the latest 12 month (so it is not 12 month back in time from a specified input date).

```r
# your data
a = expand.grid(1:2,2019,1:12)
b = expand.grid(1:2,2020,1:9)
dat = rbind(a,b)
names(dat) = c("group","year","month")
dat = dat[order(dat$group,dat$year,dat$month),]

# using dplyr
library(dplyr)

dat %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  slice_tail(n = 11) 

#> # A tibble: 22 x 3
#> # Groups:   group [2]
#>    group  year month
#>    <int> <dbl> <int>
#>  1     1  2019    11
#>  2     1  2019    12
#>  3     1  2020     1
#>  4     1  2020     2
#>  5     1  2020     3
#>  6     1  2020     4
#>  7     1  2020     5
#>  8     1  2020     6
#>  9     1  2020     7
#> 10     1  2020     8
#> # … with 12 more rows

# using base R

do.call("rbind",
  lapply(split(dat, dat$group), function(x) {
  x[(nrow(x)-11):nrow(x), ]
  }))

#>      group year month
#> 1.19     1 2019    10
#> 1.21     1 2019    11
#> 1.23     1 2019    12
#> 1.25     1 2020     1
#> 1.27     1 2020     2
#> 1.29     1 2020     3
#> 1.31     1 2020     4
#> 1.33     1 2020     5
#> 1.35     1 2020     6
#> 1.37     1 2020     7
#> 1.39     1 2020     8
#> 1.41     1 2020     9
#> 2.20     2 2019    10
#> 2.22     2 2019    11
#> 2.24     2 2019    12
#> 2.26     2 2020     1
#> 2.28     2 2020     2
#> 2.30     2 2020     3
#> 2.32     2 2020     4
#> 2.34     2 2020     5
#> 2.36     2 2020     6
#> 2.38     2 2020     7
#> 2.40     2 2020     8
#> 2.42     2 2020     9

# using data.table (from @thelatemail's comment)
library(data.table)

setDT(dat)
setorder(dat, group, year, month)
dat[, .SD[(.N-11):.N], by = group]

#>     group year month
#>  1:     1 2019    10
#>  2:     1 2019    11
#>  3:     1 2019    12
#>  4:     1 2020     1
#>  5:     1 2020     2
#>  6:     1 2020     3
#>  7:     1 2020     4
#>  8:     1 2020     5
#>  9:     1 2020     6
#> 10:     1 2020     7
#> 11:     1 2020     8
#> 12:     1 2020     9
#> 13:     2 2019    10
#> 14:     2 2019    11
#> 15:     2 2019    12
#> 16:     2 2020     1
#> 17:     2 2020     2
#> 18:     2 2020     3
#> 19:     2 2020     4
#> 20:     2 2020     5
#> 21:     2 2020     6
#> 22:     2 2020     7
#> 23:     2 2020     8
#> 24:     2 2020     9
#>     group year month
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I think the logic will work, but you need to do it by each group. Also, `nrow(dat)-11` I think is correct otherwise you go back one too many.

Comment: @thelatemail: thanks for pointing this out, I totally didn't see this ;) - updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: *data.table* translation for fun - `setDT(dat); setorder(dat, group, year, month); dat[, .SD[(.N-11):.N], by=group]`

Comment: @thelatemail: Thanks! I added it to the answer with reference to your comment.